# Access default zoom level from Google Chrome API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For my first extension I would like to make the default zoom level more accessible instead of hidden behind Settings > Advanced Settings. Ideally I would like to have a button behind the omnibar which lets me select a few default zoom options.

Now I am looking at the Chrome API to see how I could access the *default* zoom level. I have found the `getZoom()`/`setZoom()` and `getZoomSetting()`/`setZoomSetting()` [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-setZoomSettings). For the settings, I can only modify the [mode and scope](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-ZoomSettings).

**Question**: can I set the *default zoom level* via the Chome API?

The background: I have a retina screen and usually use my browser at 150% default zoom level. When I connect through an external monitor, this is a non-retina panel and I want to set it back at 100%. I am setting/resetting my default zoom level multiple times a day and this gets really annoying. As an experiment I want to build an extension for the first time.

Comment: I too have this question. After reading the docs I believe this can be done on a tab by tab basis with `chrome.tabs` API so the solution may be to brute force all tabs (could be done smartly like when a new tab is created). However, if would be nice if you found a way to manipulate default zoom directly.